# How do I solve "bad interpreter" error when interpreter is in non-standard location?

Tags: php, wordpress, bash, shell, ssh

So my first problem is that I'm hosting on GoDaddy.

Second problem is that when I try to execute the following PHP script via SSH...

```
./searchreplacedb2cli.php -h hostname -u username -d databasename -p 'password'
```

...I get a `/usr/bin/php: bad interpreter: No such file or directory` error. This is because on shared hosting, there is no `/usr/bin/php`. Instead, the php cli I want is located here:

```
/usr/local/php5_3/bin/php
```

So, I manually changed the shebang declaration in the script to...

```
#!/usr/local/php5_3/bin/php -q
```

...and sure enough, it works.

However, I don't want to have to edit this script manually. I'm looking for a way to circumvent this issue programmatically. I use this script to deploy Wordpress sites on the fly. I `wget` it from a git repository each time I use it. Furthermore it is deleted and installed regularly from a bash script, so modifying it in a text editor each time is not an option.

Is there a way to pass an alternate interpreter to a bash command? Like, "if you don't find the default interpreter, use this one instead".

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
./searchreplacedb2cli.php -h hostname -u username -d databasename -p 'password' | /usr/local/php5_3/bin/php
```

And because it's shared hosting I lack the permissions to symlink /usr/bin/php to the right place.

My next idea was to, via bash, edit line 1 of the php script using a `sed` replace command. I thought I would inquire here first for alternatives. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If it's only this host, add /usr/local/php5_3/bin/ to your $PATH, and use this shebang:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
```